# Name convention in Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I know that Automapper can automatically map from:

```
class SomeClassA 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public B Member { get; set; }
}
class SomeClassB 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

to:

```
class SomeClassADto 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Member_Id { get; set; }
    public string Member_Name { get; set; }
}
```

But how can I make Automapper map from my SomeClassADto  to SomeClassA automatically?

Comment: What you refer to is known as *flattening*. The reverse process, say *deepening*, is much harder to automate. It's not supported.

Comment: Correct. Don't un-flatten. It's not worth it. Just write the code.

Answer (score 0):

No the prettiest thing in the world, but it does work. Downside is maintenance is a pain as you add properties to the DTO and class you need to update the mapping.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(x =>
{
    x.CreateMap<SomeClassADto, SomeClassB>()
        .ForMember(i => i.Id, i => i.MapFrom(src => src.Member_Id))
        .ForMember(i => i.Name, i => i.MapFrom(src => src.Member_Name));
    x.CreateMap<SomeClassADto, SomeClassA>()
        .AfterMap((s, d, r) => d.Member = r.Mapper.Map<SomeClassB>(s));
});
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var foo = mapper.Map<SomeClassA>(new SomeClassADto() { Id = 1, Member_Id = 2, Member_Name = "Name" });
```